# Rest WP_Error always return null

Tags: api, rest-api, json, wp-error

I have dificulties in my project,

Im using Wordpress with WP Rest APi plugin. Im now making a plugin.

The problem is, whenever I return something like this :

```
return new WP_Error('rest_user_invalid_username', __('Username already exists.'), array('status' => 403));
```

Its always return null. How can I fix that ? try find solution, but still the same.

Anyhelp will appreciate... Thanks.

=========

Edited.

Im trying to debug it with this :

```
$errors = new WP_Error;
$errors -> add('rest_user_invalid_username', __('Username already exists.'), array('status' => 403));

var_dump($errors->get_error_codes());
return $errors->get_error_codes();
```

Its return :

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(26) "rest_user_invalid_username"
}
null
```

The return ALWAYS return null. Anyone?

====

I return `return 'a';` , also return null, why ?

Comment: It seems okay. Most likely you will need to test correct response, then add error response.

Comment: how can I debug that @idpokute

Comment: I returned `return 'a';` its return null too, why?

Comment: Does the built-in API work on your site? test it, /wp-json/wp/v2